# Sync data from RDS MySQL to Amazon Redshift

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm trying to Sync data from RDS MySQL to Amazon Redshift. For that, created a Data Pipeline scheduled for run once. Synced one table then tried with another table named 'roles' but it failed with the following error message "**output table named 'public.roles' doesn't exist and no createTableSql was provided**". The actual result of pipeline is as follows.

1. RedshiftTableCreateActivity - Finished
2. RDSToS3CopyActivity   - Finished
3. S3ToRedshiftCopyActivity - FAILED ("output table named   'public.roles'     doesn't exist and no createTableSql was provided")
4. S3StagingCleanupActivity - CASCADE_FAILED

For the Pipeline, tried with Truncate/OVERWRITE_EXISTING insert modes.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your redshift table "roles" does not exist.

Also, you can specify the createTableSql to be "create table if not exists roles(your table definition)"